# Images not saving to images folder in web directory

Tags: craft3

I have been following along the Up and Running with Craft 3 tutorial on craftquest.io

I created the assets volume as directed with the absolute file path

```
/c/xampp/htdocs/craftCMS/craftetest/web/images/drinks
```

I created the drinkImage field as directed. Put it in the entry type.
Created some entries and uploaded images in the drinks image fields no problems.

The problem is they don't show up in the /web/images/drinks folder at all.
Is there something I am missing?

Comment: It worked when I changed it to    C:/xampp/htdocs/craftCMS/craftetest/web/images/drinks

Comment: Can you share that as an official answer? It might end up helping someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was to start the path with an uppercase C and colon :

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/craftCMS/craftetest/web/images/drinks
```